# Replace, for loops, format, and count the replacements in Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help editing my code so the output ends up like this:

> Enter target word: red
>
> Enter replacement word: pink
>
> Number of replacements: 3

Original list:

```
blue, red, yellow, green, red, black, white, gray, blue, blue, red
```

List with replacement:

```
blue, pink, yellow, green, pink, black, white, gray, blue, blue, pink
```

Basically, I need to fix my code so that my original list and the replaced list use a for loop, but I also have to use the replace function, and at the same time I have to print the number of replacements (Which I don't know how to do).
 
Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
def replace (list1, target, replaceWord):
    new = ""
    for word in list1:
        if word == target:
            new += replaceWord + (", "[-1])
        else:
            new += word + (", "[-1])
    return new

def main():
    print ("Welcome! Enter your words one at a time and hit enter after each value.\nWhen you are done entering values, type stop.")
    inp = input ("Enter first value: ")
    list1 = []
    while inp !="stop":
        list1.append(inp)
        inp = input ("Enter first value: ")

    target = input ("Enter target word :")
    replaceWord =  input ("Enter replacement word: ")
    print()
    newlist = replace(list1,target,replaceWord)
    for i in newlist:
##     reps = ( )
##     reps += str (replaceWord)
    print ("Number of replacements: " +(reps))
    print ("Original list: " + (str (list1)))
    print ("List with replacement: " + newlist)

main()
```

Please help, thank you so much

Comment: What `(", "[-1])` is supposed to do?

Comment: I don't want it to count "stop" when I stop asking for inputs

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. `(", "[-1])` is the same as `' '`. So, what you were thinking it would do?

Comment: Can you please also add the values you input for both ```target``` and ```replaceWord```?

Comment: @fferri true, I am trying to take the extra comma after the last word

Comment: @AliNobari the target word is in list1, replalceWord is on the second list after applying the replace function

Comment: @MikeVita4 I meant the values you inputted within the program, but after looking at your output, I did realize for ```target``` you inputed **red**, and for ```replaceWord``` you inputed **pink**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def replace (list1, target, replaceWord):
    new = []
    replacements_no = 0
    for word in list1:
        if word == target:
            new.append(replaceWord)
            replacements_no += 1
        else:
            new.append(word)

    return new, replacements_no

def main():
    print ("Welcome! Enter your words one at a time and hit enter after each value.\nWhen you are done entering values, type stop.")
    inp = input ("Enter first value: ")
    list1 = []
    while inp !="stop":
        list1.append(inp)
        inp = input ("Enter first value: ")

    target = input("Enter targe word :")
    replaceWord = input("Enter replacement word: ")
    print()
    newlist, replacements = replace(list1,target,replaceWord)
    print("Number of replacements: {}".format(replacements))
    print ("Original list: " + (str (list1)))
    print ("List with replacement: {}".format(', '.join(newlist)))

main()
```

something like this should work. you do not have to stick together words in replace function, you can build new list.

Comment: for i in list1:
        print ((i), end=(", "))    . That makes the list be in one line with the comma and the space, but how do I take out the comma after the last word?

Comment: @MikeVita4 if you want to print out content from list then you can use `join` method., like this:  print('{}'.format(', '.join(list1)).  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm